# What is the Translation Strategy

Tags: magento2, javascript

There is **Translation Strategy** option with two values

- Dictionary (Translation on Storefront side)
- Embedded (Translation on    Admin side)

Path: **Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Setting -> Translation Strategy**

What's the pros and cons of these two strategies?

Comment: i just spent one day to understand why in developer mode lib/mage/validation.js went under view_preprocessed and none symlink created but copied with differences! The differences were the translations replaced because EMBEDDED was setted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Translation strategy under JavaScript settings is applied only for strings rendered from JavaScript.

**Dictionary**

All js and html files are parsed for string that should be translated (f.e. strings from "$.mage.__()" or "i18n:").
Collected string are translated and outputted to js-translation.json file.
This file is used for dynamic translation during javascript execution on frontend.

Dictionary strategy is better for development. Js files remain untouched.

**Embedded**

All js and html files are intercepted during publishing to pub/static and translation calls are replaced with result translated strings.

Embedded strategy is better on production. This strategy is performing translation only once on backend and avoids additional request for translation dictionary, so it has some positive effect on frontend performance.

Embedded strategy can not work in developer mode when static content is published using symlinks.

**Additionally**

Patterns used to find string to translate for both strategies are [configured](http://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Translation/etc/di.xml#L57-L66) in DI.