# Magento2 can't translate this sentence with "+"

Tags: magento2, javascript, localisation

In the "file vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js" in line 433 Magento2 can't translate this sentence.
[image: rules.js]
[image: file of translate]
But after remove "+" the translation is perfect.

How I can translate correct without rewrite "rules.js"?

Answer (score 0):

Translation behavior depends on strategy set in Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Setting -> Translation Strategy.

Take a look at full explanation here: [What is the Translation Strategy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121741/what-is-the-translation-strategy)

However, both strategies rely on regex pattern for replacing/collecting translatable strings. So the problem here is that string does not match the pattern.

So the only solution I see, without overriding rules.js, is to add the pattern for gathering translation files. You can do it from your module's di.xml like:

```
<type name="Magento\Translation\Model\Js\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="patterns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_pattern" xsi:type="string">~regex-pattern~</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

See existing patterns here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Translation/etc/di.xml#L63